# I have inserted a post's content in homepage.php by the post-id. The font isn't matching with the theme. How do I change font of this content?

Tags: posts, content

The code added to get the specific post's content is as below. How can I style this content now?

```
if ( is_front_page()){
    $my_postid = 30;// Here 30 is my page id
    $content_post = get_post($my_postid);
    $content = $content_post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    echo '<hr/>';
    echo $content;
    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to use developer tools in your browser to see the class and style settings of the text that does not match, and paste that information here. You could also use developer tools to show where those styles were defined, in case you have some CSS files you need to update

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks